# TensorFlow layer that converts a 2D matrix to a vector of certain length

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to build a neural network that takes in data in form of a matrix and outputs a vector but I don't know what layers to use to perform that.
My input has shape (10,4) and my desired output has shape (3,).
My current model is the following :

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256,activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256,activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
])
```

this at least results in a vector instead of a matrix but it has (10,) instead of (3,). I could probably find a way to reduce that to (3,) but I doubt I am doing the correct thing with this approach.

Comment: Please provide a sufficient reproducible input and expected output. Also, the `(10,)` and `(3,)` information you provide at the end doesn't match the code you have shared. Please be very clear and precise.

Comment: What is the (10,4) is it a sequence? or an image? or jsut a (10,4) matrix

Comment: it is just a (10,4) matrix. desired output is a vector of length 3 which i denoted with (3,). i hope thats correct. actual current output is a vector of length 10 which i denoted with (10,)

Comment: the solution that I mention below should work for you then. feel free to modify the architecture accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `(10,4)` is a matrix which doesn't represent a 10 length sequence (where you will need an `LSTM`) OR an image (where you will need a `2D CNN`), you can simply `flatten()` the input matrix and pass it through to the next few dense layers as below.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model

inp = layers.Input((10,4)) #none,10,4
x = layers.Flatten()(inp)  #none,40
x = layers.Dense(256)(x)   #none,256
out = layers.Dense(3)(x)   #none,3

model = Model(inp, out)
model.summary()
```

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_43 (InputLayer)        [(None, 10, 4)]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 40)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_82 (Dense)             (None, 256)               10496     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_83 (Dense)             (None, 3)                 771       
=================================================================
Total params: 11,267
Trainable params: 11,267
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work for me for some reason. 
`data.shape`
 _TensorShape([10, 4])_
`x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(data)`
`x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256)(x)`
`x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)(x)`
`x.shape`
 _TensorShape([10, 4])_

Comment: it does work, my bad. Apparently the Flatten() Layer doesn't do anything to the matrix because it expects the first dimension to be the batch size. If I use model.fit(data) it will internally add the batch size as a dimension(i think) and work as you described.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Flatten layer: https://keras.io/api/layers/reshaping_layers/flatten/

Or you might want to try 2d CNNs.